# My GPUs don't seem to support VK_GOOGLE_HLSL_FUNCTIONALITY1?

Tags: vulkan, hlsl, spir-v, dxc

I am currently working on a pet project vulkan renderer - which I would to extent into d3d12 in the later future for learning purposes.

While working on this I have been researching the shader compilation pipeline and decided to roll with HLSL - vulkan bindings and compiling this to spir-v using the directX compiler (DXC). When using the following optional argument "-fspv-reflect" (as I would like to use shader reflection to generate my pipelines) it compiles fine without issues. However on shader module creation during my pipeline creation it results in a device extention missing: VK_GOOGLE_HLSL_FUNCTIONALITY1.

I've tried to add this - which resulted as the title suggests in "this doesn't exist". When going through the Vulkan Info commandline tool I noticed that none of the google extensions really exist...?

Is there something I've overlooked here or that I should enable in a different manner than the standard VK_KHR/VK_EXT extentions?

Comment: It's easy enough to strip the semantic annotations from the SPIR-V before you pass in to the driver as a post-process pass, if you really can't avoid the extensions in your authoring flow.

Comment: For now I'll just work around it, until it's really necessary for me to use the semantics in shader reflection. It's just a bit strange to see a dxc compiler option that isn't allowed to run on my GPUs due to a presumably hardware constraint that's forced upon my software. (I'd like to keep my pet project as simple as possible, without making too many exceptions to issues I run into on weekly basis)

Still thank you for your mention, I'll give it a read, as I've not heard of a post process pass in a shader pipeline.

Comment: The limitation here should be driver-only; semantic annotations shouldn't modify the generated machine code, but the compiler does need to know enough to ignore them.